# Is Coulomb's Law not always accurate for neutral charges?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

Although I have never personally conducted an experiment, many online sources say that neutral and charged particles attract. However, under Coulomb's Law, I get a net force of $0$ since one of the $q$'s is $0$. Why is this?

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Please can you provide a link to an online source which says this? Are you asking about [electrostatic induction](http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/static_induction.htm#.Wm-4ha5l_IU)?

Comment: Are you talking about London/van der Waals interactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coulomb's Law describes the electric force between *pointlike* charged objects.

Things are more complicated for composite particles, which may be overall neutral, but which are composed of charged constituents.  An atom has the positively charged nucleus, surrounded by a negative electron cloud.  If the nucleus is slightly off center, then the forces it exerts do not need to cancel out the forces exerted by the electrons.  The resulting forces tend to be much weaker, but they do exist.

When quantum mechanics is taken into account, neutral composite particles tend to attract one another; this is known as the van der Waals force.  The reason is there are quantum fluctuations in the relative positions of the charged constituents of one particle; these fluctuations then exerts forces which slightly rearrange the constituents of another overall neutral atom.  The rearrangement is in such a way as to make the attractive forces between the oppositely charged parts of the two slightly stronger than the repulsive forces between the like charged constituents.

Comment: You said, *neutral composite particles tend to attract one another*. Does this also include neutrons?

Comment: Yes, even neutrons, but electromagnetic interaction may be the least of it.  The strong force may be a sort of vdW attraction between color-singlet composite particles, mediated by gluons vice photons.